# TFS 2008 and Common libraries folder structure

Tags: tfs

TFS 2008 and Common Libraries

I have created a Team Project called "Common Library" that will host code used in numerous different Team Projects throughout TFS. For sake of argument, lets say we have 2 distinct Librarys under the "Common Library" Team Projects, MailProject and LoggingProject. Other projects throughout TFS will be using the binary representation of these projects via branching and not the actual source code.

What is the best way to set up the folder structure for this Team Project? Do I add the project to the "Common Library" and simply "include" the bin/release folder as part of the project?

I have seen some examples of people creating a seperate "Deploy" folder. I assume this is synonamous with the bin/release folder?

---

We do not want the source code available in other solutions.

Currently, each project has the dll included in the project. Using a mailing module as an example, many projects need the ability to mail. The common module is very stable and mostly static.

However, what if there is a change in the mail module. It seems there would be a better way, than to check out each project and update the dll. Is it possible to allow TFS to grab the latest mail module any time a 'get latest' is called? Either explicitly or implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really require the source code for the libraries to be available in the other solutions my advice would be to include the binaries for the libraries in the projects that would use them not really having any explicit link between the two in TFS. Custom labelling of the library builds could be helpful to easily return and rebuild any chosen version of the shared libraries.

If the shared libraries require different versions for different projects then the obvious solution would to create a separate branch for every version of the libraries that need to be customised to a particular project.

TFS does not have a concept similar to SVN's 'externals' though - so if you include a branch from the shared libraries in a project and than branch that project it is very difficult to propagate changes correctly.

I suppose you could also use the [Get task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa721740.aspx) in the build and get the latest version of DDLs into the current project from another one, but verify if you can point of Workspace of another project (I have not tired it and MSDN is somewhat vague here). You might need to have a separate workspace for the shared project.

Yet another alternative would be to publish the DLLs for common components to a known location on every build of the shared libs and for individual builds to get whatever version is available from that common location (network share) even via the Copy task. This is simplistic and may cause problems with versioning of the common components but should work well enough in simple case.

Comment: We do not want the source code available in other solutions. 

Currently, each project has the dll included in the project. Using a mailing module as an example, many projects need the ability to mail. The common module is very stable and mostly static. 

However, what if there is a change in the mail module. It seems there would be a better way, than to check out each project and update the dll. Is it possible to allow TFS to grab the latest mail module any time a 'get latest' is called? Either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: I have added some more ideas. Sorry, I didn't fully understand the question initially - this comment made it much clearer.